# jQuery capturing ID of a clicked object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to retrieve the ID of the element I'm clicking on

```
$mainBox.on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.attr('id'))    
});
```

the element I'm clicking is loaded as part of an external html, this would be the line that is being clicked:

```
<li class="menuBtn" id="item03"><span class="styleClass1">03</span><span class="styleClass2">Menu Item</span></li>
```

how do I get `item03`? `event.target.attr('id')` doesn't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

`event.target` is DOM element so you need to make it a jQuery Object to use `.attr()`

---

```
$mainBox.on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
    console.log($(event.target).attr('id'))    
});
```

---

or directly use JavaScript

```
$mainBox.on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

---

```
$mainBox.on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @user3024007 Welocme Happy to help :)

Comment: btw, is it read as string? If I pass it on to function to load some content that matches this ID, will this work? `$('#foo').load ('external.html' + [passed data from this.id])` where that id represents the element to grab in the newly loaded html?

Comment: @user3024007 `this.id` will output id `item03`.You have concatenate it with string example `'ID is '+this.id+' you got it'`

Comment: wait, I'm not sure if I follow... Suppose I passed this.id to function `...function(target) { `$('#foo').load('external.html' '+target+')` ??

Comment: @user3024007 Read [this](http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/multiple-ways-to-concatenate-a-string-in-javascript/) and [this](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/string-operator.php)

Comment: thanks so much. I got it now